# Can manage to read device ID from an AVR only once

Tags: avr, isp

I'm using an ATmega48 device and my debugger is the Atmel ICE. I manage to connect to the device only once, the 2nd time causes a "failed to enter programming mode" error. Cycling power to the device enables me to re-create this as many times as I wish. I lowered the communication speed to 8KHz but that does not perform any different than 50KHz, for example. The device is new so it runs from the internal oscillator so even 50KHz should be a very reasonable speed.

Any suggestions to what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: what IDE are you using? Atmel studio? are you using AVR Dude from command line? Is it a development board, your own custom design, just a chip in a chip-carrier?

Comment: @KyranF I'm using AVR Studio 6.2 (latest build), my programmer / debugger is Atmel ICE. I'm using the device programming menu item to open the device programming window in order to communicate with the MCU. The MCU is in a 32TQFP package broken out with wires to a small pref-board that is connected to my breadboard. I usually use DIP packages on the same breadboard with no troubles. Right now only the ISP + power connections + ADC Vref. decoupling cap are connected.

Comment: do you have a reset pull-up resistor? are you sure there are no short circuits from the wires to eachother either on the pins, or on the perf board?

Comment: show us your schematic

Comment: ADC Vref decoupling cap is irrelevant, unless of course you are using the ADC while programming? Seems unlikely! You should put decoupling caps on the TWO power pins of the 32TQPF package. See the pin-out diagrams for the VCC pins that need capacitors.

Comment: @vicatcu Added a schematic to the post.

Comment: @KyranF I don't have a resistor on the reset pin, I did try adding a 10k resistor but later removed it as the behavior remained the same. There are no shorts 100% I checked with a DMM.

Comment: @user34920 you must have a 10k pull-up resistor on the reset pin and you're also not showing us the programming header wiring and you should also put some capacitance on the VCC (at least 0.1uF near the VCC pin of the chip)

Comment: @vicatcu AVRs have an internal pull-up for the reset pin, no external part needed.

Comment: @HannoBinder that's true, but you still need an external pull up on reset. See http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_application-note_avr042.pdf

Comment: @vicatcu Nope. From the document you linked to: "The reset line has an internal pull-up resistor, but *if* the environment is noisy it *can* be insufficient". I have never needed nor used one, not even on the AVR circuits I had/have running in automotive applications. In fact, too low a resistor value can actually make ICP impossible.

Comment: Do you have any other hardware connected to the AVR, esp. on the SPI lines?

Comment: And, as @vicatcu said, you *must* have a >= 100nF low ESR (e.g. ceramic) capacitor between Vcc and GND close to the chip!

Comment: I also would like to claim that your circuit is inprofessional as bypass capacitors and additional reset pull-up are most certainly needed to provide good results without much noise

Answer (score 1):

Atmel Studio 7 and Atmel-ICE

This should help:

1. `Debug -> Attach to Target` or `Debug -> STart Debugging and Break`
2. `Debug -> Disable debugWire and Close`

and then try again to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer above works for me:

Atmel Studio 7 and Atmel-ICE

This should help:

```
Debug -> Attach to Target or Debug -> STart Debugging and Break
Debug -> Disable debugWire and Close
```

and then try again to connect.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. When you have enough reputation, you can add a comment to the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try a lower speed ISP clock setting (e.g, 125KHz.) An unprogrammed AVR ATmega is running on its own internal clock of 1.0MHz, so the ISP clock must be less than 1/4 of that.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm aware of it and if you read my post you can see that I've lowered the communication rate as much as possible and saw the exact same results. Since the problem was posted I moved on :)